# nvd3.js how to properly redraw chart

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I have chart type switcher (pieChart/lineChart), date selector and one svg element.

Changing the chart type or date triggers ajax request (different urls with different response data structure for pie/line) and then redraw my chart. Like this:

```
   buildReport: function (data) {
          var that = this;
          // Format incoming data to chart's format
          this.structure = this.formatters[this.type].call(this, data);
          this.svgElem.empty(); // jQuery empty 

          nv.addGraph(function () {
              var chart = nv.models[that.type](); // that.type - pieChart or lineChart

              chart.options(that.options[that.type] || {});

              d3.select(that.svgElem)
                  .datum(that.structure)
                  .transition()
                  .duration(500)
                  .call(chart);

              return chart;
          });
      }
```

This function is called on chart type or date change (ajax request may cache for some conditions). Is it right to use svgElem.empty()? Or there is another way to destruct chart and draw another one?

And some additional questions:

1) How to draw legend in the center bottom of chart? Are there any options for this?

2) How to draw stacked area chart in "Expanded" state by default? I need to hide controls (showContols: false option) and draw expanded stackedArea chart

Thank you

Comment: I guess `.empty()` will do as well as anything else.

Answer (score 1):

To draw the chart with a style that is not the stacked you can use

chart.style("expand"); // for expanded
chart.style("stream"); // for stream